Ubuntu keeps prompting for command line arguments when attempting to launch an app
I just switched to WSL2 so that I could attach USB devices to my VM. This works now, however now applications that used to previously launch without any issues are hanging and asking for command line arguments. Like the below example.

Is there some configuration I need to do in order to stop this prompts or what do I input for no argument? The applications I am trying to launch open GUIs. I had previously resolved this issue on WSL1 by downloading Xlaunch as a server for the GUI.
